# Show that there is an injective homomorphism from $G_2 = \langle a, b \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$ to $G_1 = \langle x, y \mid xyx^{-1}y\rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm trying to show the above as simply as possible; I suspect that the method I have is somewhat overcomplicated. From looking at the Cayley diagrams of the groups, it is clear that $\varphi: G_2 \to G_1$ given by $a \mapsto x^2, b \mapsto y^2$ is such a homomorphism.

It is easy to check that this map does actually satisfy the defining relation of $G_2$, and hence induces a well-defined homomorphism.

As for injectivity, suppose that $g \in G_2$ has $\varphi(g) = e$. Since the generators $a, b$ of $G_2$ commute, we may assume without loss of generality that $g = a^mb^n$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so that $x^{2m}y^{2n} = e$.

Now, we may define $f:G_1 \to \mathbb{Z}$ to be the homomorphism with $x \mapsto 1, y \mapsto 0$ (which may easily be seen to satisfy the defining relation of $G_1$). Then we have that $0 = f(e) = f(x^{2m}y^{2n}) = 2m$, so $m = 0$, and hence $y^{2n}=e$.

It remains to show that $y$ has infinite order in $G_1$, and this is where I get a bit stuck. I can see two ways to complete the proof, but both are quite cumbersome and I feel like there should be an easier way.

The first approach I can see is to define an explicit binary operation on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ by $(p,q) * (m,n) = (m + (-1)^{n}p, n + q)$ and define a homomorphism from $G_1$ to this group by mapping $x, y$ to its generators in the appropriate way. This is quite confusing, and verifying that the defining relation is satisfied takes a relatively long time.

Alternatively, we could observe that the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ with $2n$ elements has presentation $\langle \sigma, \tau \mid \tau\sigma\tau^{-1}\sigma, \sigma^n, \tau^2\rangle$, which means that we can define a homomorphism from $G_1$ to $D_{2n}$ sending $y$ to $\sigma$, which implies that $y$ has order at least $n$. Thus, fro, since $n$ is arbitrary, we see that indeed $y$ has infinite order.

All this is quite convoluted. Can anybody see a simpler justification? Thank you!

Comment: *NB:* [$$G_1\cong {\rm BS}(1,-1).$$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group)

Comment: How is your topology? In particular, do you know that there is a ($2$-sheeted) cover of the Klein bottle by the torus?

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to construct a subgroup in $G_1$ that has the same presentation of $G_2$.

It is easy to see that if $xyx^{-1}y=e$ then 
$xy=y^{-1}x$. 
Taking inverse both sides one gets
$y^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}y$, so

$$xy^{-1}=yx.$$

Let's take $\langle x^2,y\rangle$ on $G_1$. We can see 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2y&=&xxy\\
&=&xy^{-1}x\\
&=&yx^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
With this we had shown that the subgroup complies
$\langle x^2,y\ |\ x^2y=yx^2\rangle$ and it has the same
presentation $\langle a,b\ |\ ab=ba\rangle$ of $G_2$, 
hence via the extension of the assigment given by
$$a\mapsto x^2,$$
$$b\mapsto y,$$
to a homomorphism, this would be an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that this subgroup satisfies the defining relation of the group, but how do we know that there aren't any other relations? Obviously it's clearly true, but I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: if there were another relation between $x^2,y$ (different from $x^2y=yx^2$) this would be mirrored by the generators $a,b$, which adds up to the presentation in $G_2$.

Comment: @janmarqz I don't understand your comment. You need to show that $H=\langle x^2, y\rangle$ has no extra relations, as these may follow from the relation $xyx^{-1}y$. (For example, there are one-relator groups with subgroups which cannot be defined by one-relator presentations.) Here, it is sufficient to prove that $G_1$ is torsion-free: any quotient of $G_2$ is either cyclic or contains torsion, so if $G_1$ is torsion-free then $H=\langle x^2, y\rangle$ is either trivial, cyclic, or isomorphic to $G_1$. Then $H$ isn't trivial (this is hopefully clear), and isn't cyclic (this is harder). QED

Comment: @user1729 the group $G_2$ has precisely two of those properties, isn’t that enough?

Comment: @janmarqz You have constructed a map $\phi: H\rightarrow G$; all this says is that $\phi(H)$ is a homomorphic image of $H$. You need injectivity. So the properties of $H$ are not immediately relevant (unless it was simple, for example). One way to proceed, and the way I was suggesting above, is to prove injectivity by proving that $\phi(H)$ cannot be any of the proper homomorphic images of $H$, as these all have a very specific form.

Comment: [I should say though that its pretty standard that the group $G_1$ is torsion-free. One way to see this is to notice that $G_1$ is an HNN-extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, and then to note that HNN-extensions of torsion-free groups are torsion-free.]